# Onclick in Update functon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Have a Player, that supposed to move towards a target object if the button is clicked.

Now I'm using just onClick in my button on function `Shoot()`; and it run when `targetMenu.help == 2` ,
but the object goes one frame per second & I need to click it a few times so this reaches the target.

On other hand if I put the `Shoot();` in Update, it goes smoothly but before I click the button because `targetMenu.help == 2` already.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class moveTowards : MonoBehaviour
{
    float speed = 5.0f;
    public Transform target;

    public void Update()
    {

    }

    public void Shoot()
    {
        if (targetMenu.help == 2)
        {
            transform.LookAt(target);

            transform.position += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            Debug.Log(targetMenu.help);
        }

        if (targetMenu.help == 4)
        {
            transform.LookAt(target);

            transform.position += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;

            targetMenu.help = 5;

            Debug.Log(targetMenu.help);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use coroutine and run your code from there or make Update conditional.

Snippet for conditional update

```
bool isButtonPressed = false;
public void Update()
{
    if(isButtonPressed)
       Shoot();
}

public void PressedButton()
{
     isButtonPressed = true;
}
```